# Sending mouse events to a QtQuick window in a virtual reality OpenGL scene

Tags: c++, opengl, qt5, qtquick2, virtual-reality

I am currently working on a virtual reality project that builds on OpenGL. Because I also needed some form of user interface, I thought it would be a good idea to integrate QtQuick windows into the scene. Drawing the window to a texture works without problems (I used [this example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-rendercontrol-example.html)) but I struggle to send mouse events so that my controllers can interact with it.

[Here is a quick example video on YouTube.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BUCdYA5Dt3o) In this example, the animation of the embedded GIF should stop whenever I hover over it. This works in a normal QML application but not when I manually send a *MouseMove* event.
The mouse position within the window is known (the red line in the video indicates an intersection) and I am currently sending the event through

```
QQuickWindow::sendEvent(QQuickItem* item, QEvent*)
```

where *item* is the root *Rectangle* in the qml source:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Rectangle {
    color: mouseArea.containsMouse ? "red" : "white"
    width: 600
    height: 400

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true

        AnimatedImage {
            anchors.fill: parent
            paused: mouseArea.containsMouse
            source: "test.gif"
        }
    }
}
```

The event, which I send every time an intersection between the ray and the window is found, is done with:

```
QMouseEvent* mouseMoveEvent = new QMouseEvent(
    QEvent::MouseMove, // wrong event?
    cursorPosition, cursorPosition, // Note: cursorPosition := the calculated cursor coordinates within the window
    Qt::MouseButton::NoButton,
    Qt::MouseButtons(), // is this right?
    Qt::KeyboardModifier::NoModifier);
window->sendEvent(rootItem, mouseMoveEvent); // Note: window is my QQuickWindow, rootItem is the root Rectangle
```

I am not an expert in QML (rarely used it) and would appreciate it if someone has suggestions on how to solve this. My guess is, that I am neither using the right event nor correctly sending them.

Comment: How are you handling the mouse event? have you checked if the event is being propagated in the first place? Check http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop.

Comment: I am not using QWidget and my question was about creating my own events (whenever I check for intersections between the ray from my controller and the window) which I then send to my window. The solution was to use QApplication::instance()->sendEvent(..) instead of QQuickWindow::sendEvent(..).

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution myself. Instead of using QQuickWindow::sendEvent(..) I had to simply use QApplication()::instance()->sendEvent(..).

Comment: Pretty sure you can also use the latter method so long as the event gets propagated to the handler.

Comment: What worked for me was using `QCoreApplication::sendEvent(quick_window, event);`.